# Earliest possible winning turn in Hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone's normal play mode (Constructed - pre NAXX), every card you include in your deck cannot exceed a total of 2 copies of the same card, and you have a limited amount of cards in your hand.

So, under those conditions, in which **turn** can you win if you take the enemy down as quickly as possible and the enemy doesn't concede ?

Comment: The quickest I've had is 6th turn mage. :)

Comment: Any answer would have to be based on the assumption that the opponent either does nothing to save themselves, or actively damages themselves in some way; as well as you having perfect draws for the cards you want to play in sequence. Neither of these things are going to happen often in a 'normal game', and the chances of them happening together are low. I say to urge you not to take the answers given as useful strategies, but as an interesting thought exercise purely based on numbers.

Comment: @TZHX I know it's not practice but I'm just wonder the answer of that question.

Comment: Would be interesting to see if there are any fast way including the opponent using spells/minions on themselves as well.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A win on your first turn is possible if you play as a Druid against another Druid who plays Millhouse on their first turn.

In the video below, the opposing druid opens with an Innervate and summons Millhouse Manastorm. Millhouse's battlecry says: *"Enemy spells cost (0) next turn."* (Which means your spells cost (0) on your opening turn.)

Next, the player uses this opportunity play just shy of their *entire deck* and win. A pivotal card is Gadgetzan Auctioneer, which gives them a card every time they play a spell - giving them a virtually endless supply of 0-mana spells.

#### Source

Comment: fixed your wording a bit (though correct me if I'm wrong as I can't watch the video at work).

Comment: @z- Thank you! In this particular example, they're both druids. Have a good day at work!

Comment: @z- Your changes aren't right tho, it is if you play as a druid, not against. Just the enemy play of Millhouse was enough here. Although because he was a druid he could have popped out Millhouse without a coin :/

Comment: @Lyrion the thing is, Millhouse takes 2 crystal, so there's no way for the winning player to win on turn 1 technically as the person to go first has no coin. The only way to pop out a millhouse on their turn 1 is if they were a druid and used innervate.

Comment: @z- Yep so basically it would be a first turn win with a druid vs a druid, when the enemy druid starts with Millhouse. Because no other class could get the card draw out I guess.

Comment: @Lyrion the winner class can be mage as well, 2x pyro 2x fireball would do it.  Though it would be silly to hang on to those cards through the mulligan phase.

Comment: Maybe a brief explanation could accompany the video in this answer. I'm sure some people won't be able to follow what happened via the video alone. In this example, Millhouse plays a vital role, but the Gadgetzan Auctioneer ensures that the druid wins in one turn (a Mage could do it without the Auctioneer).

Comment: I've suggested an edit with such a summary.

Comment: @Lyrion any class can get the card draw out. Auctioneer is Neutral.

Answer (score 18):

I found a recent Reddit post of a turn 3 win as a mage (now known as Winner) versus a mage (unfortunately now known as Loser).

The winning mage went second, so got an extra card and coin.

Starting deck:

- Sorcerer's Apprentice **(your spells cost 1 less)**
- Mana Wyrm **(whenever you cast a spell, gain 1 attack)**
- Ice Lance
- Arcane Missiles
- Coin

The Sorcerer's Apprentice and the Mana Wyrm are the reason this turned out the way it did. But not to forget the nice amount of luck of drawing so many spells to begin with.

Turn 1:

- Winner draws Frost Bolt.
- Loser plays nothing.
- Winner uses Mana Wyrm (1 mana).

Turn 2:

- Winner draws Mirror Image.
- Loser pings Winner's Mana Wyrm (hits it for 1 damage).
- Winner uses Sorcerer's Apprentice (2 mana).
- Arcane Missles (0 mana) - 3 damage to hero - Mana Wyrm is at 2 attack.
- Coin (0 mana) - gains 1 mana back - Mana Wyrm is at 3 attack.
- Frost Bolt (1 mana) - 3 damage to hero - Mana Wyrm is at 4 attack.
- Ice Lance (0 mana) - 4 damage to hero - Mana Wyrm is at 5 attack.
- Mirror Image (0 mana) - Mana Wyrm is at 6 attack.
- Mana Wyrm attacks - 6 damage to hero.
- Loser takes: 3 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 damage and is left with 14 hp.

Turn 3:

- Winner draws Fireball.
- Loser plays Arcane Intellect.
- Winner uses Fireball (3 mana) - 6 damage to hero - Mana Wyrm is at 7 attack.
- Mana Wyrm attacks - 7 damage to hero.
- Sorcerer's Apprentice attacks - 3 damage to hero.
- Loser takes: 6 + 7 + 3 = 16 damage.
- Winner wins :)

This is without the Loser inflicting any damage on themselves. Obviously I am unsure if the other player had the means to kill the Mana Wyrm at any point, but I suspect they would've if they could.

This is just one example, and as the game progresses, Blizzard may re-balance certain cards making the above and other quick kills impossible.

But I hope that gives you an idea. As TZHX pointed out in the question comments, you can't rely on these strategies to win you games consistantly :)

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/1wtyln/turn_3_win_as_mage/)

Answer (score 9):

The turn 3 victory can also be completed easily with the Shaman with just 3-4 cards thus removing the need for lucky draws beyond the initial hand:

Turn 1 Dust Devil (3/1 windfury overload 2) + coin + Dust Devil
Turn 2 12 Damage (4 attacks)
Turn 3 Flametongue Totem (20 damage) or 2x rockbiter weapon (24 damage)

Note you have 1 spare crystal on turn 3 for 1 lightning bolt or earth shock to remove any taunts.

Note 2, you can subsitute a young dragonhawk for a second dust devil but you will need both the flametongue and rockbiter, or 2x rockbiter and a lightning bolt for the finishing blow.

Of course, this is highly susceptible to any form of removal, but a windfury shaman deck has enormous early+midgame damage output and is great for farming daily quests as its guarenteed to be a fast win or loss.

Answer (score 5):

**It's possible to win on turn 2** with Mimiron's Head in Druid, using double innervate and 2 target dummies turn 1. Turn 2 you use Crazed Alchemist to swap the V07TR0N's attack and health and swing for 4*8 = 32 damage.

Note that even going second you only start with 4 cards in your hands, so you have to topdeck whichever of the 5 components for t1 that you don't have. Then you have to topdeck Crazed Alchemist t2. So this is ridiculously unlikely.

I think this is the earliest win that doesn't require your opponent to make a specific play.

Answer (score 1):

**Three.**

Mage (you) vs Priest (The opponent):

You go second.

Turn 2: *Priest* plays Millhouse Manastorm

Turn 2: *You* Unstable portal --> Archmage Antonidas. 7 ---> 4 Mana

Turn 3: *You* Coin. Archmage Antonidas. Enjoy free fireballs with any spell.

Yes, this has happened to me. Yes, I was the priest...

Answer (score 1):

As a Shaman you can

1. Coin Whirrling Zapomatic
2. Play Flametongue, Attack with Whirrler for 2x5 damage
3. Play 2 x Rock Biter on Whirrler, he attacks for 2 x 11 damage, GG

However it requires an inactive opponent in terms of taunt, heals, and taking out your minions...so pretty uncommon

Answer (score 1):

Lowest possible "moves" (button clicks/etc)

I've got one that is a twist, which ends on either turn 2 or 3, but the same number of "moves" if you count click end turn (passing) as a "move"

Turn 1 - Paladin

1. Draws Holy Wrath x 2
2. Clicks End Turn

Turn 2 - Druid

3. Plays Coin
4. Plays Millhouse
5. Clicks End turn

Turn 3 -

6. Plays Holy Wrath x 1 (With Molten Giant top-decked)
7. Plays holy wrath x 1 (With any other giant or Deathwing top-decked)

Completely theory, but I think that's just 7 moves. It could be shortened to two turns, with the druid starting and using innervate + millhouse, Which I think would take it to 6 moves, but i've only barely thought through it in my head.

I've seens several vids with 2 or 3 turn wins, but this one would be pretty difficult to show as the odds of getting millhouse in the druids hand, while getting both holy wraths, plus a molten + one other 10+ card top decked when played stretches the probably out enough that it could take months to get it "right" just to show it.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Rogue**
I have had this happen twice before on constructed, it is not the most reliable turn 3 win, but it is possible and usually results in a turn 3 concede.  Also, you could play 1x or 2x Young Dragonhawk and follow it up with the same turn 2 play for a turn 3 kill if the creatures are not removed (this could work without the coin).

Turn 1 Opp: opponent does nothing
Turn 1 Rogue: Coin into Defiant Ringleader (2-2 and 2-1 on board)

Turn 2 Opp: casts a creature with 2 toughness (knife juggler, etc)
Turn 2 Rogue: Backstab creature, then Cold Blood x2 (I always put one on each unless vs mage or druid).  Attack with 6-2 and 6-1 for 12.

Turn 3 Opp: plays nothing with taunt or heal
Turn 3 Rogue: Swing for 12 more leaving opponent at 6 life, rogue can deal the final points of damage in several ways on turns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

As a mage with 2 pyroblasts and two fireballs in the opening hand vs a druid with two innervates and millhouse you can win on your first turn.

Answer (score 0):

Many theorycrafts have been presented but I'd like to answer with a pretty reliable/viable deck:

 The Murlock - Murloc Warlock

Best case scenario:

**Turn 1 (as 2nd player)**

Double Murloc Tidecaller (Board: 2/2, 1/2)

**Turn 2**

Murloc Tidehunter (Board: 4/2, 3/2, 2/1, 1/1) (Damage: 4+3=7)

**Turn 3**

Murloc Warleader (Board: 7/3, 6/3, 4/2, 3/2, 3/3) (Damage: Turn 2 7+7+6+4+2=26)

**Turn 4**

Anything from keeping your board, to Darkbomb/Bluegill Warrior, to normal Soulfire or Power Overwhelming.

The deck works quite nicely for climbing and is a lot of fun. Getting quite a lot of friend requests asking what the frog just happened to them :)

Answer (score -3):

0, from your opponent disconnecting.

Comment: The question specifically says _and the enemy doesn't concede_.

Comment: *Technically* a disconnection isn't a concession, though the effects are the same. Still not a great answer though.